# Cross-Origin Golang com gorilla/mux

Tags: cors, golang

Em minha aplicação estou utilizando o pacote `gorilla/mux` junto ao `gorilla/handlers` para habilitar/configurar o `CORS` da minha aplicação, atualmente possuo uma api em `GO` e uma aplicação frontend em `vue`, na minha aplicação `vue` que fica na porta `8080` eu tento chamar a api em `GO` que fica na porta `8081` e mesmo com todo o `CORS` configurado continuo recebendo o erro de `Cross-origin`

```py
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    allowedHeaders := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With"})
    allowedOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    allowedMethods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})

    router.HandleFunc("/api/get/{name}", getCard)
    router.HandleFunc("/api/autocomplete/{name}", autoComplete)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", handlers.CORS(allowedHeaders, allowedOrigins, allowedMethods)(router))
}
```

Se eu acesso o `endpoint` `localhost:8081/api/autocomplete/random` pelo navegador ou até mesmo pelo terminal com `curl` as informações são exibidas normalmente, se eu tento realizar um `GET` da minha aplicação front-end em outra porta recebo o erro abaixo;

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8081/api/autocomplete/random. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

O que mais preciso configurar além desses `handlers` que já estou usando?

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar como Header permitido o `Content-Type`, a variável `allowedHeaders` ficará assim:

```
allowedHeaders := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"})
```